# How to prove integer division inequality in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I need to prove: `256 * (x / 256) <= 256 * x / 256`, or more generally `forall a b c : N, c > 0 -> a * (b / c) <= a * b / c`. This is true since either b is divisible by c and they are equal or it's not and multiplying first can inflate the number and result in greater precision. However, I could not find any theorem in the standard library that proves this, and no automatic tactic I know (auto, intuition, easy, zify and omega) worked. If it helps, I also know that `x < 256 * 256`, but checking all 65536 cases is not a good proof...

Comment: An outline of my initial thoughts: if there's a result or you can prove that `x * d <= n -> x <= n / d` then you can apply that, and then use that `(a * (b / c)) * c = a * ((b / c) * c) <= a * b`.

Comment: The lemma is in the standard library. Do `Requre Import Arith. Search (_ * (_ / _)).` and you can find `Nat.div_mul_le`. So `intros; apply Nat.div_mul_le.  now destruct c.`   is enough for your general lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my specific case I was able to solve it like this:

`rewrite (N.mul_comm 256 x).`

This switches around the right side to `256 * (x / 256) <= x * 256 / 256`.

`rewrite (N.div_mul x 256).`

This reduced the right side to `256 * (x / 256) <= x`.

`rewrite (N.mul_div_le x 256).`

After this automated tactics are sufficient.